# Question mark appears instead on content on calling static block

Tags: magento-1.9

I have made a static block for korea website for korean language. In this the content is in korean language. Then i have called this static block in phtml file. The block is called but the content which should appear in korean language is appearing as question mark.

I have also attached the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Please check database table 'cms_block' and check if the content is stored correctly.

Comment: No the content is not saving correctly.What should i do next

Comment: @sarvagya I just re verified. The content is saving correctly in db

Comment: Can you paste the static block content to your question? Also let me know the language you are using.

Comment: looks like encoding issue to me.

Comment: <div class="radio"><label> <input type="radio" required="" value="self" name="buyingoption" />상업적인 목적으로 위 물건을 구매하는 것이 아니며, 관세청에 등록된 본인의 개인통관고유부호와 이름을 정확히 기재하였습니다. </label> <label> <input type="radio" value="other" name="buyingoption" />상업적인 목적으로 위 물건을 다른 사람을 대신해서 구매하는 것이 아니며, 관세청에 등록된 본인의 개인통관고유부호와 이름을 정확히 기재하였습니다. </label></div>

Comment: I have added the static block . It is in korean language

Answer (score 1):

There was the issue of `utf` encoding . check if the value is saving in database and from the server end `utf` encoding is enabled. One of the temporary fix is to call the data statically in phtml file.